# Code for a simple singin page using php

Tags: php, html

I am new to programming. I need a simple login page code for PHP which displays an error message in the same page for incorrect login details and redirected to the account page incase of correct login details. The code should remember the activity and redirect to the account page of the user if he has closed the page without login out. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Log in page

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<h3>Login Page</h3>
<form action="trylog.php" method = "post"><!--action redirects to trylog.php -->
<label for="username">Username</label> <input type="username" id="usename" name="username"><br /><br /><!--username label defined -->
<label for="password">Password:</label> <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br /><br /><!--password label defined -->
<button type = "submit">Login</button><!--submit button defined -->
</form>
</html>
```

Account page

```
    <html>
<title>Login</title>
<body>

<?php
session_start();    //resumes previous session based on indentifiers from POST attribute in login.php 
$usr = "admin";     //usr keyword defined
$psw = "password";  //psw keyword defined
$username = '$_POST[username]';
$password = '$_POST[password]';
            //$usr == $username && $psw == $password
if ($_SESSION['login']==true || ($_POST['username']=="admin" && $_POST['password']=="password")) 
            //checking for correctness of username and password
{
 echo "password accepted";
    $_SESSION['login']=true;
            //successful login confirmation
 echo "<br><a href='http://localhost/login/login.php'>Logout</a>"; 
} 
else 
{ 
 echo "incorrect login";
            //incorrect login message
}
session_destroy();  //destroys session
 ?>  
  </body>
  </html>
```

Thanks 
Navaneeth

Comment: stackoverflow is meant to be a place to help others with broken code or problems, not to develop or find solutions to things which are readily available via a [Simple](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+ajax+login+tutorial) [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+ajax+authentication+tutorial) [Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+ajax+login+script) . Please review some of those links before posting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to learn about [what kinds of questions are allowed here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This is what i am dealing with. @panther

Comment: All the search results use databases. I need one which doesn't use a DB. Prefer the matching from a hard coded array. Sorry if i have broken your rules. @John C

Answer (score 0):

1. `session_start` has to be **before** output, so move that before `<html>` etc. (output is a space before `<?php` too. `<?php` has to be the first sequence in your code.
2. what you meant by `$psw` and `$usr` variables? You have them in form, delete them.
3. When you work with variables, don´t use quotes - you can use double-quotes marks, not single. Better is to use no quote marks: `$username = $_POST['username'];`. On the other hand, the key should be in quote marks, elsewhere you work with undefined constant `username` - if constant doesn´t exists, PHP work with the same string.
4. Condition on line 12 will never be `true` because you test there a `SESSION` which hasn´t been set before. You set this session on your line 16, but only if this session already exists (line 12). It´s logical nonsense :-)
5. Why you create variables `$username` and `$password` when you doesn´t work with them?
6. Before you work with `$_POST`, lines 9 and 10, you must check if the form was sent, so `if (isset($_POST['username'])) {}`.